# yahoo gifshot javascript numframe bug

Tags: javascript, animated-gif

I am using yahoo gifshot library to create gifs from videos. A user can upload a video and, afterwards, I dynamically create a gif from that video. The problem is, that user uploads a two-second duration video but the gif is only saved as one second duration...

here is code :

```
 gifshot.createGIF({
                'video': [U + 'Content/convertedVideos/bla.mp4'],
                'gifWidth': 800,
                'gifHeight': 400,
                ...
```

i've added numframes property which works fine but another problem is it repeats both first shows one second duration gif and then two second gif

code :

```
  'video': [U + 'Content/convertedVideos/bla.mp4],
            'gifWidth': 800,
            'gifHeight': 400,
            'numFrames': 20,
```

image :  [image]

look at first load one sec gif and after two sec gif 
how can i save only two second duration gif? please help sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem like you. I solved it by reducing 1 or 2 frames.
Video duration: 2s => 2000 ms => 20 frames (it's theory). numFrames should be 20 - 2 = 18 frames.

***More info:***
// The number of frames to use to create the animated GIF
// Note: Each frame is captured every 100 milleseconds of a video and every ms for existing images
'numFrames': 10,